# Find duplicate in a list of a list of integers

Tags: c#, algorithms, list

What is the best way to find the duplicates in a list of a list of integers (no matter what position thay are in)? 
I don't necessary need code just the best way to go about this problem.

eg:

```
List<List<int>> TestData = new List<List<int>>
{
     new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
     new List<int> { 2, 1, 3 },
     new List<int> { 6, 8, 3 },
     new List<int> { 9, 2, 4 },
};
```

The idea is that this will return

```
2x) 1,2,3
1x) 6,8,3
1x) 9,2,4
```

I've been breaking my head over this seemingly very simple question but for some reason I can't figure it out.
Hope someone is able to help, Like I said code not necessary but greatly appreciated.

Comment: questions about code are off-topic here. You should post in StackOverflow instead.

Comment: consider using a java.util.Map<integer,List<integer>> to parse the lists. after that build a class that take the map as a parameter and build the response. not the best approach but you can start from it...

Comment: @linuxunil I understand but it wasn't as much about the code as it was trying to get an explanation how to go about this problem.

Comment: ok. break it in two steps. First you need to read and group the data. second you need to read the groups and build the output. How far are you on that?

Comment: Do you care about the ordering of the elements in the lists shown in the result?

Comment: This isn't a code question, it's an algorithm question, which is on topic here.

Comment: It appears that you are really looking to find the duplicate 'sets' not 'lists'.  The distinction being that order matters in lists and it does not in sets.  This might seem like pedantic vocabulary nitpicking but if you put your data into sets instead of lists, the problem is a bit easier because two sets are equal if they contain the same elements.

Comment: @JimmyJames And just what is a *set* in C#.   Neither List nor Array implement iComparable in .NET.

Comment: @Paparazzi I don't see why it would need to.

Comment: @JimmyJames What would TestData be?  There is no set in .NET.

Comment: @Paparazzi Right.  It sucks not to have basic stuff like that but there is [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JimmyJames Well that would be a problem as HashSet does not allow duplicates and the objective is to count duplicates.

Comment: @Paparazzi Correct. Duplicate sets.

Comment: @John: You need to define what makes two lists equal. It seems you disregard the order of numbers, but do you also disregard duplicate numbers - ie. is { 1, 2, 3 } a duplicate of { 3, 2, 2, 1 } ?

Answer (score 2):

- Sort each once
- First compare length
- Then compare element by element
  As soon as an element does not match then the List does not match

This site is not about code but this works

```
IEqualityComparer<List<int>> listComparer = new ListComparer();
testData.ForEach(l => l.Sort());
var distinctLists = testData
    .GroupBy(j => j, listComparer)
    .Select(group => new { List = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

public class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            if (x[i] != y[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(List<int> x) => x.Count;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to sort if they have different lengths. I would say that a solution to this problem would also depend on the size of the problem, if known.

Comment: @nbro I am going to assume that each length has more than one.  If not then just wasted one sort.

Answer (score 2):

**Brute force approach:**

- First sort every list in `TestData`
- Then [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort `TestData` (so that duplicate lists will necessarily follow each other)
- Finally iterate over `TestData`.  For every list, count how many following lists are equal to find out the duplicates (and if duplicates are found, skip them in the main iteration).

**Smart approach:**

- Create a list of in which you'll store a checksum for each list in `TestData` along with its index, and its length, and sort it by checksum and length.
- iterate trough this list.  For every group of consecutinve items having the same checksum and length, proceed like the brute force approach, but only for the corresponding (potentially equal) lists.

This approach is based on the fact that only lists that have the same checksum and length could be equal, to reduce the number of lists to be sorted and compared.

This second approach is more complex to implement but has the advantage of performing the more expensive sorting and comparing only when it's really  necessary.  You could certainly adapt the algorithm to replace sorting with a smart comparison

---

Here is a small implementation of the first approach, including [an elegant lexicographic sorting of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33028197/3723423) :

```
    // Sort every list in the list 
    for (int i = 0; i < TestData.Count; i++) 
         TestData[i].Sort();

    // Order the list of lists using a lexicographic sort
    TestData.Sort((x, y) => {
        var result = x.Zip(y, Tuple.Create)
                       .Select(z => z.Item1.CompareTo(z.Item2))
                       .FirstOrDefault(k => k != 0);
        return result == 0 && !x.Any() ? -1 : result; 
    });
    var sorted = TestData; 

    // Iterating through the ordered list of list to spot the duplicates
    List<int> t=null;
    int cpt = 1;  
    foreach (var l in sorted)
    {
         if (t != null)  // do nothing for the very first list
         {
             // in all other cases, compare list with the previous one
             var a = t.SequenceEqual(l);
             if (a) // if it's the same, increment occurrence counter
                 cpt++;
             else   // if not, show the duplicates and restart counting
             {
                 Console.Write("{0} x ", cpt);
                 WriteList(t);
                 cpt = 1;
             }
         }
         t = l; 
     }
     if (t!=null)  // process the last element outside the loop
     {
         Console.Write("{0} x ", cpt);
         WriteList(t);
     }
```

THe, with the following test input:

```
    List<List<int>> TestData
        = new List<List<int>>  { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
                                 new List<int> { 1, 8, 2 },
                                 new List<int> { 2, 1, 3 },
                                 new List<int> { 9, 2, 4 } };
```

it will produces the expected output:

```
    2 x  1 2 3
    1 x  1 2 8
    1 x  2 4 9
```

Comment: I think this fails as only sorts on First

Comment: @Paparazzi oh yes, thanks !  I messes up the lexicographic sort, by just comparing the first element on each list, instead of element by element.  I've edited and corrected the code

Comment: See what I added to my answer.  There is a slicker approach.

Comment: @Paparazzi Nicer ! Your text alone was not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

If you group by the sorted version of each list, then take the length of each group, this is very simple to implement.  In Scala, this is:

```scala
val groups = testData groupBy {_.sorted} mapValues {_.length}
groups foreach println
/* output:
   (List(3, 6, 8),1)
   (List(2, 4, 9),1)
   (List(1, 2, 3),2)
*/
```

Obviously, if you have requirements for ordering or output formatting, that adds complexity.  I don't know C#, but LINQ has [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) which should work very similarly.

Comment: In .NET List does not implement iComparable

Comment: That's surprising.  There is a parameter for a custom `IEqualityComparer(TKey)`, although I don't know how easy it is to use.

Comment: The custom implementation of the `IEqualityComparer` can just passed to the `GroupBy` method [see here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151645/104803).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define what is means that a list is duplicated. It seems you don't care about order so { 1, 2, 3 } is a duplicate of { 2, 1, 3 }, but do you also disregard duplicate numbers so { 1, 2, 3 } is a duplicate of { 2, 1, 1, 3 } ?
2. Write an `IEqualityComparer` using the definition for equality you decide on. (Eg. compare as sets or as ordered lists)
3. Use `GroupBy` with the equality comparer to group similar lists, so you can get the `Count` of the duplicates in each group.

Answer (score -2):

```
    testData.forEach(list -> list.sort((o1, o2) -> o1 - o2));
    testData.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((integers, aLong) -> System.out.printf("%dx) %s\n", aLong, integers));
/*
   OUTPUT:
   2x) [1, 2, 3]
   1x) [3, 6, 8]
   1x) [2, 4, 9]
*/
```

Comment: Does not look like C# to me

Comment: that's java, but the concept could be easily translated to LINQ query or lambda expression, whichever one you prefer.